# У меня проблема с кодом

Tags: java

Дан одномерный массив, который содержит не более 50 целых чисел. Заменить каждый элемент массива суммой соседних элементов. Если соседних элементов нет, то число оставить без изменения.
Вот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Laba5_1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = new int[10];
        int aP[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Введите элемент массива: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Введенный массив: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i != 0 || i != 10) {
                int aP[j] = array[i - 1] + array[i + 1];
                j++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Преобразованный массив: " + aP);
    }
}
```

Comment: В чём заключается проблема то? )

Comment: в `i != 0 || i != 10`, думаю...

Comment: Похоже здесь нужно i < 0 && i < 9 . Исключаем крайние элементы. А условие i != 0 || i != 10 всегда будет истинным, независимо от i.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, вы имеете в виду следующее

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i != 0 && i != 9) {
                   ^^^^^^^^
            int aP[i] = array[i - 1] + array[i + 1];
                ^^^^^
        }
    }
```

В цикле вместо магического числа 10 лучше использовать свойство массивов `length`. Например,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < aP.length; i++) {
```